# Using a href with Post within a list

Tags: javascript, html, list, forms, href

I am looking for a solution after trying all different option for 5 hours . I am not a big HTML or Javascript person but I tried.

I have a List coming from the Database which is listings of services. Each Service gets their own unique ID. At the moment I send the ID via the URL but this is not preferable,

Within each list element I have a Picture and button and a link using the persons name.

I tried to use javascript to take the value from a value in the href line and sent that to the url which worked but it seems like the server saw that as a different session and hence the webpage did not display the full editable listing,

This was the script

```
<script>
            function myFunction(test) {
            
            var url = "/portal/vendorlistingsadd";
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", url);
                
            
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                      console.log(xhr.status);
                      console.log(xhr.responseText);
                   }};


                xhr.send(test);
            }
   </script>
```

then did

```
<a href="#" onclick=myFunction('${serviclist.listing_id}')><img src=${serviclist.picture} alt="" class="img-fluid"></a></div>
```

other problems I had was due to the same 'name' been on each row in the list, I could not extract the correct one.

So basically the only way I can see it working is to send the data via url .

If anyone has any suggestion I would try each one

Thank you

****UPDATE

```
<form action="/portal/vendorlistingsadd/editlisting" method="post">
                                                                                                
                                                                                                </form>
```

and the second line

```
<button class= "btn-lg" name ='${serviclist.listing_id}'  type = "submit">  <img src="${serviclist.picture}"/> </button>
```

Comment: Use a `<button>` instead of an `<a>`. If it’s not an anchor, it should be a button. Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, if I make it as a button and then use that button to post the information , on the server side I only receive the value of the first row in the list. It does not matter which button I press. I will try it out and maybe background image the picture

Comment: So I took your advise and it worked, No script required. Thank you